# How to reverse both x and y axis in Octave?

Tags: plot, octave

I want to create a scatter plot with both axis reversed.
How to do this in Octave? (I already have the points to plot in two column vectors X and Y, of equal size)

The `axis("ij")` option only reverts the y axis, but not both.

[image]
An example of a scattered plot with reversed axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code in "figure" section:

```
set (gca (), "xdir", "reverse")
set (gca (), "ydir", "reverse")
```

[Source](https://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Reversing-the-x-Axis-When-Plotting-td3949680.html)